# SQL Server : how to remove the first 2 digits of a 10 digit number and add 2 fixed digits at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I need to accomplish the following: I have a column `ID_NUMBER` with a 10 digit number. I need to remove the first two digits from the beginning of the number, and add 2 more fixed digits at the end.

Example:

`4795522061` would turn into `9552206101`.

I am always going to need to add a `01` at the end.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: `substring(id_number, 3, 100) + '01'`.

Comment: What's the datatype of the field you're working with here?

Comment: Where in SSIS do you have to do this? Control Flow, or Data Flow or Scripting Task? That will determine the recommended method.

Comment: @STLDeveloper - DataType Float.

Comment: @Shiva - Nothing with SSIS, my mistake on adding the tag

Comment: Since the datatype is a float, how do you expect to handle digits that are to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: @clos82 Ok. You should specify the datatype of your `ID_NUMBER` column also.

Comment: The data was an import from excel which created a table and assigned the datatype of float by default. Should I re-import the data making the ID_NUMBER column datatype  varchar or try converting the column to varchar first, then doing the substring approach?

Answer (score 1):

This seems very straightforward:

```
SELECT RIGHT(ID_NUMBER,8) + '01'
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always a 10 digit number you can also apply a modulo instead of string operations:

```
cast(ID_NUMBER as bigint) % 100000000 * 100 + 1
```

This extracts the last 8 digits, shifts two digits to the left and adds 1.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that commented and the explanations! The answer above worked!!!! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple `UPDATE` command with syntax like Lamak's post. **This will alter the value in your ID_NUMBER column, so there will be no going back from this once you have commited the transaction.**

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET ID_NUMBER = RIGHT(ID_NUMBER,8) + '01'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty straight forward request. I would just use that magical function Right and cast it as bigint:

```
 SELECT CAST((RIGHT(NUMBER, 8) + '01') AS BIGINT)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Code only comments are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Could you expand on this answer?